# I have a problem with saving text that user types

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Basically, I wanted for quite a time to make a text editor. (Not for coding reasons). I've been working on it since 2 days ago.
Everything is fine, until I found out that when you "save as" the project, and after you write something, and you click the button to save, it doesn't save it. Please help, I am new to tkinter, and I was inspired by tutorials
Thank you.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
filename = ''
def new_file():
    filename = "Untitled"
    text.delete(0.0, END)
def open_file():
    file1=filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r')
    data = file1.read()
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert(0.0, data)
def save_file():
    filename = file1
    data = text.get(0.0, END)
    file1 = open(filename, "w")
    file1.write(data)
def save_as():
    file1 = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode = 'w')
    data = text.get(0.0, END)
    file1.write(data)
gui = Tk()
gui.title("Wind Text Editor")
gui.geometry("600x600")
text = Text(gui, height=600, width = 600)
text.pack()
mymenu = Menu()
list1 = Menu()
list2 = Menu()
list3 = Menu()
list4 = Menu()
list1.add_command(label='New', command = new_file)
list2.add_command(label='Open File', command = open_file)
list3.add_command(label='Save File', command = save_file)
list3.add_command(label='Save File As', command = save_as)
list4.add_command(label='Exit', command = gui.quit)
mymenu.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = list1)
mymenu.add_cascade(label = 'Open', menu = list2)
mymenu.add_cascade(label = 'Save', menu = list3)
mymenu.add_cascade(label = 'Exit', menu = list4)
gui.config(menu=mymenu)
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: The line "file1.write(data)" is not enough to create a file and to fill it with the text user wrote. You should use "open(file1, "w").write(data)" command instead of that line -such as you did above in save_file() function-. Of course it is more reasonable to create a new variable which is set to file and to use the variable to close the opened file. If the line I specified works, let me know so I will post it as an detailed answer.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, `0.0` is not a proper index.Text widget indexes are strings, not floating point numbers, and the very first character is `"1.0"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly overwriting your filename with the file1 file handle. Remove `filename = file1` from the save_file(): function.

```py
def save_file():
    data = text.get(0.0, END)
    file1 = open(filename, "w")
    file1.write(data)
```